# Is it possible to determine when Windows Update is scheduled to auto-reboot?

Tags: c#, windows-update

I have a C# Windows services that needs to know in advance if and when Windows Update has scheduled a system reboot to complete an update.  Is there any way to monitor this from a C# application?  The service runs on unmanned Windows 7 & 10 machines.  I have spent a considerable amount of time searching for this and have come up empty-handed.  I examined the [Windows Update Agent (WUA) API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387292(v=vs.85).aspx) but did not find anything applicable (perhaps I missed something?).

Comment: My system (win 10 pro) writes a 1074 to the system log for planned windows updates. https://superuser.com/questions/1028374/determine-whether-a-shutdown-is-pending EDIT: specifically it says `Operating System: Upgrade (Planned)`

Comment: Thanks, UpTide.  That may be useful as a last resort but (from the included link) it appears that you can't determine when the shutdown is to occur.  I'll dig deeper down this line of thinking to see if I can uncover more and let you know.